# DotNetBrowser LoadHTML Stylesheet not used

Tags: dotnetbrowser

When using DotNetBrowser LoadHTML (ie. HTML in a string), it does not read the external CSS file specified in the  element. If I save the HTML and then load into DotNetBrowser with LoadURL it renders fine. Why would this work with LoadURL but not LoadHTML?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check whether the following Chromium switches help you to resolve the described issue?

```
BrowserPreferences.SetChromiumSwitches(
    "--disable-web-security", "--allow-file-access-from-files");
```

These switches are used to allow your HTML code access all its resources. Here is a link to the article describing the Chromium switches: https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000110017-chromium-switches

In addition, it is recommended to specify the absolute paths to the files in your HTML to be sure that they are resolved properly.